# Вывод каждого символа на следующую строку C#

Tags: c#

Пользователь вводит нужное ему слово, а программа должна вывести символы этого слова поочерёдно на каждую строку. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ну это уже совсем на азы языка вопрос, т.е. видимо, учебное задание, а такое тут не приветствуется, если вы ничего не пытались вообще самостоятельно сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите строку");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Результат:");
    foreach (var ch in userInput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ch);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Строка пустая");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @user448769 Не забывайте поставить галку возле ответа -- это добавит рейтинга автору ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
var source = "Hello, world";
foreach (var ch in source)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ch);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пользователь сам должен ввести слово. Например ввёл слово "Солнце" и программа должна вывести поочерёдно на каждую строку

Comment: @user448769 `var source = Console.ReadLine()`? серьезно?)

Comment: Решил освоить язык C#) Извините за глупые вопросы